# Using sed command to

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, debian

I'm trying to be able to read a file, replace a variable or instead add it at the bottom if it hasn't been already specified.

I've had a bit of help to get this far:

```
#!/bin/bash

function replaceappend() {
  if ! sed "/$2/{s//$3/;h};"'${x;/./{x;q0};x;q1}' $1
  then
      echo "$3" >> $1
  fi
}

replaceappend "/etc/ssh/sshd_config" "Port 22" "Port 123"
```

However, after running this script the contents of the original file seem to be untouched, and remain at Port 22 with nothing appended.

In this example it's using a speicfied exit code on sed using the q flag to see if it finds it or not, and then appending it if not.

Can anyone see why this code may not work?

Comment: your q's title is missing a word.

Comment: Did you mean to use `sed -i`?

Comment: `Can anyone see why this code may not work?` - Yes, it is immensely complicated and full of arcane language constructs. sed is for simple substitutions on a single line, for anything else just use awk. Most of the sed constructs you are using became obsolete in the mid-1970s when awk was invented. If you edit your question to show some sample input and expected output we can help you create a MUCH simpler, clearer, and probably briefer solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* this is what you're trying to do:

```
$ cat tst.sh
function replaceappend() {
    awk -v old="$2" -v new="$3" '
        sub(old,new) { replaced=1 }
        { print }
        END { if (!replaced) print new }
    ' "$1" > /usr/tmp/tmp$$ &&
    mv /usr/tmp/tmp$$ "$1"
}

replaceappend file "Port 22" "Port 123"
replaceappend file "Port 22" "Port 123"

$ cat file
line 1
Port 22
line 3
Port 71
line 5

$ ./tst.sh

$ cat file
line 1
Port 123
line 3
Port 71
line 5
Port 123
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the help. Using your code and this command ```replaceappend "/etc/ssh/sshd_config" "Port 22" "Port 123"``` seems to leave my file untouched and "Port 22" at the top of the file. I will keep testing it because I may have got it wrong my end. This is on a debian 7 install.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed & bash):

```
function replaceappend() {
    sed '/'"$2"'/{s//'"$3"'/;h};$!b;x;/./{x;b};x;a'"$3" $1
}
```

The function uses the original sed statement but instead of returning an exit code at the end of the file it checks the hold space (which has been used as a flag to mark if a substitution has taken place) and either does nothing when a substitution has already taken place or appends the required string to the end of the file when the substitution has failed.